# from the orientdb console.sh ,I could't get the right server-configuration

Tags: configuration, console, orientdb

### Expected behavior and actual behavior

I set the db.pool.min and db.pool.max in the orientdb-server-config.xml ,

```
<properties>
    <entry value="10" name="db.pool.min"/>
    <entry value="30" name="db.pool.max"/>
    <entry name="client.channel.minPool" value="50"/>
    <entry name="client.channel.maxPool" value="300"/>
    <entry value="true" name="profiler.enabled"/>
    <entry value="info" name="log.console.level"/>
    <entry value="fine" name="log.file.level"/>
</properties>
```

,but I can't get db.pool.min =10 and db.pool.max =30 from OGlobalConfiguration.dumpConfiguration(System.out)

this is my OGlobalConfiguration.dumpConfiguration(System.out) result:
OrientDB 2.1.13 configuration dump:
I get 
     client.channel.minPool = 1
     client.channel.maxPool = 100
     db.pool.min = 1
    db.pool.max = 100

Answer (score 0):

From the console, before launching the command "config get db.pool.min", you need to connect to the server (eg: connect remote:localhost/db username password) and then execute the command "config get db.pool.min", this should see the value that you set in config.xml

Otherwise from java API:

[image]